# Assets Uploader Just Spins and Does Nothing Else

Tags: assets, craft-pro

I am using Craft locally, at `localhost:8888` with free MAMP. I am unable to upload images using the Assets uploader. The images in Assets were dropped in manually in their directory.

- Permissions for Craft are 774 (`/app`, `/config`, `/storage`)
- File system path: `/Users/myuser/repos/craft-learn/craftapp/public/assets/i/artists/`
- URL: `http://localhost:8888/assets/i/artists/`
- version 2.6.2958

What should I check?

[image: Asset Upload Spins Endlessly]

Comment: You definitely should check the response body of the request that uploads the file via Ajax with the developer console. There's probably a PHP notice or an error somewhere and you should be able to see it there. If it comes up empty, you can also try craft/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log logfile.

Comment: Have a look in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`, there you will find `craft.log` (probably alongside a few more numbered log files which are older) and a `phperrors.log`. You can get more details in your logs as well by enabling `devMode` in your config. You can read up on this here: https://craftcms.com/support/logs-and-backups

Comment: @AndrisSevcenko Thank you! Your suggestions to look that deeply brought me to find that i need to run MAMP Pro in an admin account. MAMP free in a standard user doesn't work for full CraftCMS functionality.

Comment: @StephenHamilton Thank you! Your suggestion too to look that deeply brought me to find the solution described above.

Comment: @isral for posterity it's probably worth writing your own solution as an answer an accepting it so that people who find this by a google search know what the answer to your specific issue was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use MAMP Pro instead of MAMP free. i cannot answer with complete authority why, but MAMP Pro has abilities that MAMP free doesn't.